# How do I create an Android Activity using Tab Navigation for earlier SDKs?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-tabs

I'd like to support Android SDK 8, and be able to use tab navigation. 
When I attempt to create an activity using tabs with the GUI wizard, I get the following error:

[image]

What's the best way to implement tabs and still support these older versions of the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

select none in the navigationType i.e the first option in the navigationType dropdown

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I'd like to use Tab navigation with this earlier version of the API. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: dont select tab in navigation type.